# MacPorts: installing packages systemwide

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, mac-osx

On Snow-Leopard, it seems that when I install a package, it requires to be "reinstalled" for every user. How do I do a system-wide install?

Thanks!

Comment: Not here. I just add ports with sudo port install and it works for every user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default all packages installed by MacPorts are installed within the /opt/local tree.  Make sure each user either has this reflected in their path, or calls the binary with the full path.

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin
```

Failing that, check to make sure the prefix variable is set correct in the macports.conf file.  The global file can be found at:

> /opt/local/etc/macports/macports.conf